Turings Machine transition grapg ( check if more 0's than 1's)
I have a problem with creating a Turing machine in a simulator that checks if there are more 0's than 1's in 2 numbers combined. For example 00110#10100001 should return accept state since there are 8 zeros and 5 1's. Is anyone able to come up with a transition graph?
I tried creating a transition graph, but I end up with more than 20 different states, and errors in simulation, so my solution doesn't work for all cases.

The general idea is to cross out one 0, then one 1, repeat until you run out of zeros or ones and then decide.

An algorithm could go like this:

Scan the input from left-to-right and wipe out exactly one "0" with "#"
If no "0" was found: reject

Scan the input from right-to-left and wipe out exactly one "1" with "#"
If no "1" was found: accept

Repeat from the top.


To implement this, you need to split the first phase into the state where you haven't found a "0" yet, and where you did find it (and wiped it out). We could call these two states "find0" and "found0" respectively.
Similarly, you need for the second phase the states "find1" and "found1".
Add to these the accept and reject states, and you have six states, with the following transition table:



current state
symbol read
symbol to write
move head
new state




find0
1,#
copy
right
find0


find0
0
#
right
found0


find0
blank
copy
right
reject


found0
0,1,#
copy
right
found0


found0
blank
copy
left
find1


find1
0,#
copy
left
find1


find1
1
#
left
found1


find1
blank
copy
left
accept


found1
0,1,#
copy
left
found1


found1
blank
copy
right
find0



As a state diagram:

Implementation
Here is a runnable JavaScript snippet. The machine is created with the above transition table. A sample input is loaded on the tape and you can step through the process, or load another input:


createTuring({
  transitions: [
    { state: "find0",  read: "1#",              move: "R", nextState: "find0"  },
    { state: "find0",  read: "0",   write: "#", move: "R", nextState: "found0" },
    { state: "find0",  read: "_",               move: "R", nextState: "reject" },
    { state: "found0", read: "01#",             move: "R", nextState: "found0" },
    { state: "found0", read: "_",               move: "L", nextState: "find1"  },
    { state: "find1",  read: "0#",              move: "L", nextState: "find1"  },
    { state: "find1",  read: "1",   write: "#", move: "L", nextState: "found1" },
    { state: "find1",  read: "_",               move: "L", nextState: "accept" },
    { state: "found1", read: "01#",             move: "L", nextState: "found1" },
    { state: "found1", read: "_",               move: "R", nextState: "find0"  },    
  ], 
  initState: "find0",
  tape: "100110#001101",
});
<script src="https://trincot.github.io/turing.js"></script>




Thank you for your response. I think i just tried to hard to maintain the best time complexity. My algorithm was continuously checking for either 0 or 1 and then entering a loop to find the equivalent and balance it off. I applied your idea, though changed it a little bit adding one state for reject, since rejecting from state find0 will give reject every time the tape comes back to the blank symbol. Thanks again !

You're welcome! Not sure I understand the need for the extra state, as the "coming back to the blank symbol" happens in state "found1", where there is no rejection. The direction is changed there (the long arrow back in the state diagram) and in "find0" there is no immediate reject (only if no "0" is found in the forward scan). I had implemented this in a simple simulator and it works fine for me.

Added that implementation to my answer. No additional state is needed.
